# How to create a JSON from checkbox value?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I have table with ng-repeat values which I fetch from mysql(Codeigniter). 
and this table has checkbox which I select to create a JSON.

```
<tr ng-repeat="subject in subject_list | orderBy: 'sub_branch' | filter: search_subject">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" 
ng-true-value="{{subject.sub_id}}" 
ng-model="checkmodel.subject.sub_id"  
ng-true-value="subject.sub_id"
ng-name="subject_name"></td>
<td>{{subject.sub_name}}</td>
<td>{{subject.sub_branch}}</td>
<td>{{subject.sub_code}}</td>
<td>{{subject.sub_sem}}</td>
<td><select ng-model="checkmodel.subject.section" ng-disabled="!checkmodel.subject.sub_id">
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                <option value="C">C</option>
                                <option value="D">D</option>
                            </select></td>
                        </tr>
```

Problem 1: I'm only able to select one checkbox.

Problem 2: When I select a value from dropdown, the same value automatically selected in other dropdown boxes.

Here is sample JSON: `{"subject":{"sub_id":1,"section":"A"}}`

Comment: What does using two ng-true-value attributes mean?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan i accidentally added them two times. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both of the problem, I would suggest you inspect the elements to make sure that the `ng-model` is not same. You have to have different models for every checkbox as well as select menu.

Comment: let me try i will let you know if it worked or not, Thanks